# Understanding the notion of two norms being consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m \times n $ matrix. Define the matrix norms :

$$ ||A||_F = \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2 }, \; \; \; ||A||_2 = \sup_{||x||_2 = 1} ||Ax||_2 $$

where $|| \cdot ||_2$ is the standard euclidean norm and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am given that if we can show $||A x||_2 \leq ||A||_F ||x||_2$ then it follows that $|| \cdot ||_2 $ and $|| \cdot ||_F $ are consistent norms. What is the meaning of being consistent? does it mean that $||A||_2 = ||A||_F $ for any $A$ ?? in other words, does it mean that these two matrix norms are just the same?

Comment: This is just a "downgrade" of your previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425161/showing-two-matrix-norms-are-equivalent/1425512

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion here. You use the standard Euclidean vector norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ to defined a matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ using the same notation (which specializes to the vector norm when applied to a vector); then you state an inequality that uses only the vector norm, not the generalized matrix norm; and then you ask a question about the matrix norm being equal to the Frobenius norm. I think the confusion will be resolved if you reflect upon these various usages.

For the definition of consistency between a matrix norm and two vector norms that your inequality seems to refer to, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Consistent_norms).

Comment: @user135395: I'm just giving you advice on how to use the site; you don't have to follow it. I, for one, have become very wary about answering follow-up questions in the comment space. It tends to lead to long discussions in the comments and buries answers in comment threads instead of making them accessible to everyone in the intended Q&A format of the site. So I'm not answering your follow-up question in a comment, whether you consider it new or not.

Comment: @user135395 Comments are for clarification. If you have a new question to ask, use the [ask a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link at the top right of your screen. I have removed off-topic comments from this thread.